# Programmatically update a bound checkbox in a GridView using an asp:ButtonField in ASP.NET 2005

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, visual-studio-2005

The GridView is bound to an Access Table, but I want to update the checkbox using the asp:ButtonField.  The best I've been able to do is replace the checkbox with a string value.  Below is the code I have now:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCommand
    If e.CommandName = "check" Then
        'Enable Editing on the GridView
        GridView1.EditIndex = GridView1.SelectedIndex
        'Assign value to the row selected
        Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
        'Assign selected gridview row
        Dim selectedRow As GridViewRow = GridView1.Rows(index)
        'Assign checkbox cell as table cell
        Dim selectedCell As TableCell = selectedRow.Cells(0)

        'Assign a value to the checkbox, **but instead is replacing the checkbox**
        selectedCell.Text = "True"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to use [`.FindControl()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx).

The `GridViewCell` is not the same thing as a `CheckBox` control inside it. You code should probably look more like:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCommand
    If e.CommandName = "check" Then
        'Enable Editing on the GridView
        GridView1.EditIndex = GridView1.SelectedIndex
        'Assign value to the row selected
        Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
        'Assign selected gridview row
        Dim checkBox As CheckBox = GridView1.Rows(index).FindControl("checkBoxIdGoesHere")

        checkBox.Checked = true 'or false or whatever based on your command.
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Won't that just set your locally-scoped "checkBox.Checked"  to true?  Will setting it that way make it back to the GridView?

Comment: It'll make it back to the `GridView`. The direct reference in your answer is functionally equivalent (or, at the very least, is in C# and should be in VB).

Comment: @jwiscarson It worked with your code!  After I changed it to a TemplateFiled...!  I hadn't remembered to do that!

Answer (score 1):

I've had my own share of problems accessing controls from within GridViews.  I solved something similar about a month ago.  Assuming that your checkbox control is the only thing in that cell, you could try something like this:

```
'Assign a value to the checkbox
CType(GridView1.Rows(index).Cells(0).Controls(0), CheckBox).Checked = True
```

Try that and see if it works.  If not, post back and we can take another look.

Comment: You really, really should not access cells and controls like this. If you ever move the control from one column to another or change the order of controls in a cell, your code will break. This is way too highly coupled.

Comment: @jwiscarson I completely agree, but GridViews are so finicky with how they allow control access, that out of all the things I could suggest that had the highest chance of success.  And if it helps with what the OP is trying to accomplish, he can always re-factor it.  But getting it working first can sometimes be tricky.

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23 Got an error: 'Checked' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.Control'...

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23 now it says: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.LiteralControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox'

Comment: Does @jwiscarson's solution work for you?  His is a better answer than mine.